# Windows 8.1 update keeps failing

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, updates, windows-8.1-upgrade

I know this has been covered a little in previous questions, but I still can't pinpoint what is wrong or what is preventing the 8.1 update. First time on the forum, so please correct me if I'm in the wrong place.

Here is my a copy of my superr.log. It was too big to fit in here. Here is a link to it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxX6CIDigV64XzhGYmR0WTRRNnM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE. I ran the dism restorehealth. Here is the summary.

```
Checking System Update Readiness.

(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt    (Fixed) amd64_microsoft-windows-lddmcore_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_049240036d50fb73
(p) CSI Manifest Corrupt    (Fixed) amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack-msg_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_97691157b4cb9d7d
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt (Fixed) amd64_prncacla.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_en-us_deb867c6ae915466\prncacla.inf_loc
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt (Fixed) amd64_prndlcl1.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_en-us_52bad903ff58cfd8\prndlcl1.inf_loc
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt (Fixed) amd64_prndlclf.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_en-    us_57b03bf8947c4315\prndlclf.inf_loc

Summary:
Operation: Detect and Repair 
Operation result: 0x0
Last Successful Step: Entire operation completes.
Total Detected Corruption:  5
CBS Manifest Corruption:    0
CBS Metadata Corruption:    0
CSI Manifest Corruption:    2
CSI Metadata Corruption:    0
CSI Payload Corruption: 3
Total Repaired Corruption:  5
CBS Manifest Repaired:  0
CSI Manifest Repaired:  2
CSI Payload Repaired:   3
CSI Store Metadata refreshed:   True
DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=800F081F
```

However in the CMD results it shows it fails:

```
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation failed. Either the repair source was not found or the comp
onent store cannot be repaired.

Error: 0x800f081f

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Comment: There was an update released recently to address corruption problems dealing with Windows Update. Have you attempted to install that [update](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-releases-fix-for-windows-update-corruption-errors-7000026582/)?

Comment: Yes, update still failing.

Comment: **Specific errors please.**

Comment: I am sorry; I don't access random google drive documents.  **The error I want is connected to the update that resolves the Windows Update corruption anyways.**

Comment: You have serious integrity issues run DISM to repair the installation.  The error logs indicate system dll files are corrupt

Comment: I have updated the question with the results of the DISM log

Comment: You will need to provide it a valid repair source.

Comment: Never done this before. How do I provide/where do I get a valid repair source. I just ran the command Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Comment: There are several guides on this particular command tool

Comment: I have read several articles about using DISM and WinPE to capture your windows partition to use as a source for RestoreHealth. But I want to make sure I capture the right partition. When I boot from WinPE and display my partitions I see I have 6 partitions.
OEM,
Recovery,
System,
Reserved,
Primary,
Recovery,

Which partition should I capture for RestoreHealth? Recovery?

Comment: Considering your partition is no longer a valid source I am not sure the reason you would use it.  You need to use an external online or perhaps installation media to solve your problem at this point.

Comment: Could I use the image of a new Windows 8.1 computer that is not corrupt?